# Google wallet - how to customise top level items?

Tags: google-pay, google-wallet

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to customise the cards displayed in the initial screen of the google wallet? i.e when you first open google wallet you see a list of your passes - can you add an extra line of text on this?

And where can I find the details of what displays in this view?  For example looking here:

https://developers.google.com/wallet/tickets/transit-passes/qr-code/overview/add-to-google-wallet-flow

They have this example, but I can't find where in the documents they give further information about what displays by default in this view:

[image: Example from google docs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't really change what Google uses for those previews.

But I liked your question so much that I made a simple guide for anyone else that has this problem but wants to know the default JSON values that get mapped onto previews for passes in Google Wallet: https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/google-platform/how-to-customize-previews-for-google-wallet-passes

Comment: Thanks!  yeah that was the conclusion I came to too after a bunch of reading and a bit of experimentation.  But your tutorial is waaaay more user friendly and concise than the google docs :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell on this, the item you have highlighted is actually a "Passes Class" entry of an event ticket. The text there is actually the event name as seen in the section "2. Create a Passes Object." You can see this in the image they have in that section:
[image]

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the documentation here but it seems to me that this text you're asking about is the event text itself when the "Add to Wallet" feature is used and the Passes Object is imported into Wallet.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping it would be something like that but it seems it's not that simple.  

For example, for a transit pass depending on whether you supply a single ticketLeg or multiple ticketLegs google seems to use some logic to decide to only show the origin\destination and the date (but the date only shows for a single leg ticket) on the initial pass display. And I can't find any documentation pointing to what will display, so it's very much trial and error...